# TTFError at / Can't open file "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp52b4p0wi.ttf"

Tags: python, django, font-face, html-to-pdf, xhtml2pdf

**I'm trying to render the Arabic content to the pdf, through the xhtml2pdf library in Django**
*but as mentioned in the documentation, xhtml2pdf comes up with limited supported languages, that's why I'm using the manual **.ttf** file, but it is showing me this error*

> **Here's my views.py**

```
def generate_pdf(request):
    pdf = render_to_pdf('index.html')
    if pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        filename = "Invoice_.pdf"
        content = "inline; filename='%s'" % filename
        download = request.POST.get("download")
        if download:
            content = "attachment; filename='%s'" % filename
        response['Content-Disposition'] = content
        receipt_file = BytesIO(pdf.content)
        return response
```

> **utils.py**

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from xhtml2pdf import pisa


def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("utf-8")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

> **Then main thing my .html file, with *.ttf* font format**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Gift PDF</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family: ArialUnicode;
            src: url("D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\static\fonts\arial-unicode-ms.ttf");
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: "ArialUnicode", sans-serif;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="headings">إلي</div>


</body>
</html>
```

> Here's my TRACEBACK.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 4.0.6
Python Version: 3.8.8
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'pdf_project']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 523, in open_for_read
    return open_for_read_by_name(name,mode)
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 463, in open_for_read_by_name
    return open(name,mode)

During handling of the above exception ([Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Zbook\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpqk76pgoq.ttf'), another exception occurred:
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 530, in open_for_read
    return BytesIO((datareader if name[:5].lower()=='data:' else rlUrlRead)(name))
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 476, in rlUrlRead
    return urlopen(name).read()
  File "C:\Users\Zbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Zbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\Zbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 547, in _open
    return self._call_chain(self.handle_open, 'unknown',
  File "C:\Users\Zbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Zbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1425, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)

During handling of the above exception (<urlopen error unknown url type: c>), another exception occurred:
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\ttfonts.py", line 151, in TTFOpenFile
    f = open_for_read(fn,'rb')
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 534, in open_for_read
    return open_for_read(name,mode)
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 532, in open_for_read
    raise IOError('Cannot open resource "%s"' % name)

During handling of the above exception (Cannot open resource "C:\Users\Zbook\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpqk76pgoq.ttf"), another exception occurred:
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\pdf_project\views.py", line 10, in generate_pdf
    pdf = render_to_pdf('index.html')
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\pdf_project\utils.py", line 12, in render_to_pdf
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("utf-8")), result)
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\document.py", line 116, in pisaDocument
    context = pisaStory(src, path, link_callback, debug, default_css, xhtml,
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\document.py", line 68, in pisaStory
    pisaParser(src, context, default_css, xhtml, encoding, xml_output)
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\parser.py", line 794, in pisaParser
    context.parseCSS()
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\context.py", line 481, in parseCSS
    self.css = self.cssParser.parse(self.cssText)
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\w3c\cssParser.py", line 443, in parse
    src, stylesheet = self._parseStylesheet(src)
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\w3c\cssParser.py", line 545, in _parseStylesheet
    src, atResults = self._parseAtKeyword(src)
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\w3c\cssParser.py", line 667, in _parseAtKeyword
    src, result = self._parseAtFontFace(src)
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\w3c\cssParser.py", line 843, in _parseAtFontFace
    result = [self.cssBuilder.atFontFace(properties)]
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\context.py", line 176, in atFontFace
    self.c.loadFont(names, src,
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\context.py", line 853, in loadFont
    file = TTFont(fullFontName, filename)
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\ttfonts.py", line 1178, in __init__
    self.face = TTFontFace(filename, validate=validate, subfontIndex=subfontIndex)
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\ttfonts.py", line 1072, in __init__
    TTFontFile.__init__(self, filename, validate=validate, subfontIndex=subfontIndex)
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\ttfonts.py", line 439, in __init__
    TTFontParser.__init__(self, file, validate=validate,subfontIndex=subfontIndex)
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\ttfonts.py", line 175, in __init__
    self.readFile(file)
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\ttfonts.py", line 251, in readFile
    self.filename, f = TTFOpenFile(f)
  File "D:\Software House\Extras\Tests\pdfTest\main_project\venv\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\ttfonts.py", line 161, in TTFOpenFile
    raise TTFError('Can\'t open file "%s"' % fn)

Exception Type: TTFError at /
Exception Value: Can't open file "C:\Users\Zbook\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpqk76pgoq.ttf"
```

Comment: Please post your traceback.

Comment: sorry I didn't get you, what's your point Sir @SUTerliakov ?

Comment: Provide *full* error message you get in the terminal, not only last line. It should begin with `Traceback (most recent call last):`.

Comment: This is famous ttf parser error in old pdf generators. I already send issue and fix for that. For fast solution you can get ttf font studio and remove all meta-information from font file (author, commentary, additional info). Problem exists if meta has not latain symbols.

Comment: @SUTerliakov, Sir I've added the TRACEBACK.

Comment: @MaximDanilov
Can you please help me out in solving this issue?

Comment: Please tell me which TTF Font Family you want to add. Can I see the tmpqk76pgoq.ttf?

Comment: @MaximDanilov,
Sir it's the ArialUnicode.ttf font-family,
I'm giving the path of this font, in my current project directory,
but as you can see in the abve traceback, it goes in the C drive to look for the file, in the AppData and temp folder,
however as I mentioned earlier I'm giving the path of ArialUnicode file which is present in my project directory which is D:/,.
Sir is there any need to install something for like unicode tool for windows, or something else?

Comment: is there any answer you could find Usama, if so can you provide please ? This seems like a very annoying  bug:/

Answer (score 0):

Problem is: on Windows, the temporary file is deleted before it can be used in PDF rendering.

One of solves:

Executed before pisa.CreatePDF: `pisaFileObject.getNamedFile = lambda self: self.uri`

https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf/issues/623

Answer (score 0):

I use this method "pisaFileObject.getNamedFile = lambda self: path" in callback:

```
import os from django.conf
import settings from xhtml2pdf
import pisa from xhtml2pdf.files
import pisaFileObject

def link_callback(uri, rel):
    # use short variable names
    sUrl = settings.STATIC_URL      # Typically /static/
    sRoot = settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0]    # Typically /home/userX/project_static/
    mUrl = settings.MEDIA_URL       # Typically /static/media/
    mRoot = settings.MEDIA_ROOT     # Typically /home/userX/project_static/media/
    # convert URIs to absolute system paths
    if uri.startswith(mUrl):
        path = os.path.join(mRoot, uri.replace(mUrl, ""))
    elif uri.startswith(sUrl):
        path = os.path.join(sRoot, uri.replace(sUrl, ""))
    else:
        path = uri
        
    pisaFileObject.getNamedFile = lambda self: path

    # make sure that file exists
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
        raise Exception('media URI must start with %s or %s' % (sUrl, mUrl))
    return path

def render_xhtml2pdf(context):    template_path = 'template.html'    # Create a Django response object, and specify content_type as pdf    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')

   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="template.pdf"'    # find the template and render it.    template = get_template(template_path)    html = template.render(context)

   # create a pdf    pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('iso-8859-2'), dest=response, link_callback=link_callback)

   # if error then show some funy view    if pisa_status.err:
      return HttpResponse('We had some errors <pre>' + html + '</pre>')    return response
```